# Add new column to the existing data set

Tags: r

```
  Date     City     Temp
  1/1/2012 Liverpool  10
  1/2/2012 Madrid     20
  1/3/2012 Milan      40
  1/4/2012 Istanbul   35
  1/5/2012 Munich      10
```

I need to add another column in this data set with County column name. If the df$City is Madrid, Country will need to be Spain. I now this is a very small data set, I need to be able to do this programatically thin R?

I would like my new data frame to look like this:

```
Date     City        Temp   Country
--------------------------------------
1/1/2012 Liverpool    10    England
1/2/2012 Madrid       20    Matrid
1/3/2012 Milan        40    Italy
1/4/2012 Istanbul     35    Turkey
1/5/2012 Munich       10    Germany
```

Any pointers how I would do this in R?

Comment: do you want to add rows or columns?  What does the row/column you'd like to add look like?

Comment: And you want it recognize the country automatically?

Comment: I would like to insert a country as a column and check each row. for example, if it is matrid, I need to insert Spain to that row. Since Madrid will appeared multiple times in this data set. Every time, I see Madrid, I should put Spain as the country.

Comment: You're going to need another table that maps City to Country.

Comment: it would be cool if there was a library that did this for us...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no definite mapping since cities with the same name may exist in multiple countries.

Comment: @user1317221_G it is a *package* if speaking about R

Comment: yup @SvenHohenstein I just tried `world.cities[world.cities$name == "Liverpool" ,]` in `maps` `data(world.cities)`
yes @GavinSimpson package.

Answer (score 2):

On way with your exact data provided is:

```
 df <- read.table(text= " Date     City     Temp
                 1/1/2012 Liverpool  10
                 1/2/2012 Madrid     20
                 1/3/2012 Milan      40
                 1/4/2012 Istanbul   35
                  1/5/2012 Munich      10",header=TRUE)


df$Country <- ifelse(df$City == "Liverpool", "England",
                     ifelse(df$City == "Madrid", "Spain",
                         ifelse(df$City == "Milan", "Italy",
                           ifelse(df$City == "Istanbul", "Turkey", "Germany") )))
```

However I am assuming you may have more cities and countries, in which case something like:

```
countrydf <- read.table(text= " City Country
                           Liverpool  England
                           Madrid     Spain
                           Milan      Italy
                           Istanbul   Turkey
                           Munich     Germany",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


merge(df,countrydf, by="City")
```

note:

had a look in package `maps`, which could be useful to you

```
library(maps)
data(world.cities)
head(world.cities)

world.cities[world.cities$name == "Istanbul" ,]
```

Comment: I like to use ifelse, and I followed your code, not working for me. Can you just put one liner for if the city is Liverpool, Countyr is England?

Comment: is it becasue of your typo in `Munich`? Her is one line as you want but the code above works: `df$practice <- ifelse(df$City == "Liverpool", "England", "Not England")`

Comment: I get this error:  df$New<- ifelse(df$City == "Liverpool", "England")
Error in ifelse(df$City == "Liverpool", "England") : 
  argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: yes because you are not giving `ifelse` an option what to do if `df$City` is **NOT** `Liverpool` compare what you have written to my comment above.....the function is `ifelse`. so you should read your code as *if liverpool then england, if not then something else*. your not providing *something else*. In my example in the comment the *something else* is `"Not England"`. type `?ifelse` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the cities are mapped to countries in your situation (i.e., are they mapped in a `list`, `vector`, `data.frame`, or something else altogether?), it's hard to guess what the right answer is for you. Here is one way, where the city-country mapping is in a list:

```
df <- read.table(text="Date     City     Temp
1/1/2012 Liverpool  10
1/2/2012 Madrid     20
1/3/2012 Milan      40
1/4/2012 Istanbul   35
1/5/2012 Munich      10", header=TRUE)

city.countries <- list(England=c('Liverpool', 'London'), 
                       Spain='Madrid', 
                       Italy='Milan', 
                       Turkey='Istanbul', 
                       Germany='Munich')

df <- transform(df, Country = with(stack(city.countries), ind[match(City, values)]))
#       Date      City Temp Country
# 1 1/1/2012 Liverpool   10 England
# 2 1/2/2012    Madrid   20   Spain
# 3 1/3/2012     Milan   40   Italy
# 4 1/4/2012  Istanbul   35  Turkey
# 5 1/5/2012    Munich   10 Germany
```